# librarian-chef install shows getaddrinfo: Temporary failure in name resolution (SocketError)

Tags: ruby, vagrant, chef-infra, cookbook, librarian

I am installing cookbooks in VM Ubuntu environment using Vagrant. For cookbook management, I have used `librarian-chef`.

### Vagrantfile

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  # instance identifier for future use
  config.vm.box = "vanilaUbuntux64"
  # preconfigured Vagrant box, later just use only vanilaUbuntux64
  # size is 447 MB
  config.vm.box_url = "http://opscode-vm-bento.s3.amazonaws.com/vagrant/virtualbox/opscode_ubuntu-12.04_chef-provisionerless.box"
  # shared folder for whithin local system and VM
  config.vm.synced_folder "./app" , "/rezoomex", create:true
  # static IP for machine
  config.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.2.25"
  # default file picked up after system is up
  # this will install steps require for running chef
  config.vm.provision :shell, :path => "setup.sh"
end
```

### setup.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
sudo apt-get update -y
# do not touch these lines
sudo apt-get install curl -y
sudo apt-get install zip -y
sudo apt-get install git -y
sudo apt-get install vim -y
# rvm 
gpg --keyserver hkp://keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys 409B6B1796C275462A1703113804BB82D39DC0E3
curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
source /usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm
# ruby using rvm
rvm install 1.9.3
rvm install 2.1
rvm use 2.1 --default
# librarian-chef installation
sudo gem install librarian-chef
# sudo DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive aptitude install -y -q chef
```

### Cheffile

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
#^syntax detection
site 'https://supermarket.chef.io/api/v1/cookbooks'

cookbook "apt"
cookbook 'java', '~> 1.31.0'
cookbook 'solr', '~> 0.3.0'
```

### output after `librarian-chef install`

```
vagrant@vagrant:~/testchef/libChefTest$ librarian-chef install
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:879:in `initialize': getaddrinfo: Temporary failure in name resolution (SocketError)
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:879:in `open'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:879:in `block in connect'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/timeout.rb:76:in `timeout'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:878:in `connect'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:863:in `do_start'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:852:in `start'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@global/gems/librarian-chef-0.0.4/lib/librarian/chef/source/site.rb:353:in `block in http_get'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@global/gems/librarian-chef-0.0.4/lib/librarian/chef/source/site.rb:348:in `loop'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@global/gems/librarian-chef-0.0.4/lib/librarian/chef/source/site.rb:348:in `http_get'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@global/gems/librarian-chef-0.0.4/lib/librarian/chef/source/site.rb:238:in `cache_remote_object!'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@global/gems/librarian-chef-0.0.4/lib/librarian/chef/source/site.rb:228:in `cache_remote_json!'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@global/gems/librarian-chef-0.0.4/lib/librarian/chef/source/site.rb:173:in `cache_metadata!'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@global/gems/librarian-chef-0.0.4/lib/librarian/chef/source/site.rb:102:in `metadata'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@global/gems/librarian-chef-0.0.4/lib/librarian/chef/source/site.rb:71:in `version_uris'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@global/gems/librarian-chef-0.0.4/lib/librarian/chef/source/site.rb:44:in `manifests'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@global/gems/librarian-chef-0.0.4/lib/librarian/chef/source/site.rb:443:in `manifests'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@global/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/dependency.rb:117:in `cache_manifests!'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@global/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/dependency.rb:113:in `manifests'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@global/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:152:in `block in resolving_dependency_map_find_manifests'

        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@global/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:165:in `block (2 levels) in scope_resolving_dependency'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@global/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:179:in `block in scope_checking_manifests'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@global/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:223:in `scope'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@global/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:178:in `scope_checking_manifests'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@global/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:164:in `block in scope_resolving_dependency'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@global/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:223:in `scope'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@global/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:163:in `scope_resolving_dependency'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@global/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:151:in `resolving_dependency_map_find_manifests'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@global/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:62:in `recursive_resolve'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@global/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:50:in `resolve'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@global/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver.rb:23:in `resolve'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@global/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/action/resolve.rb:26:in `run'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@global/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/cli.rb:169:in `resolve!'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@global/gems/librarian-chef-0.0.4/lib/librarian/chef/cli.rb:41:in `install'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@global/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@global/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@global/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor.rb:359:in `dispatch'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@global/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/base.rb:440:in `start'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@global/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/cli.rb:26:in `block (2 levels) in bin!'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@global/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/cli.rb:31:in `returning_status'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@global/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/cli.rb:26:in `block in bin!'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@global/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/cli.rb:47:in `with_environment'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@global/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/cli.rb:26:in `bin!'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@global/gems/librarian-chef-0.0.4/bin/librarian-chef:7:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/bin/librarian-chef:23:in `load'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/bin/librarian-chef:23:in `<main>'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@global/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@global/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution. It was merely isolation network issue( sometimes firewall issue). I `reload` vagrant and everything starts working fine